# After casting numerical as varchar 0 digit disappears

Tags: sql, casting, teradata

Too make things simple here is the example that illustrates everything

```
select cast('0.0000' as numeric(26,4)) -- returns 0.0000 as should
select cast(cast('0.0000' as numeric(26,4)) as  varchar (32)) -- returns .0000
```

but

```
select cast(cast('1.0001' as numeric(26,4)) as  varchar (32)) -- returns 1.0001
```

How to save that 0 without `case` statement or it`s the only way? And  why does it happen?

Comment: MS SQL or Oracle SQL?

Comment: @Matt its a teradata

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Teradata, but have you triend to cast your `numeric(26,4)` first as some kind of `format` and then to `varchar` ?

Comment: @ConsiderMe Firstly I verify that `0.0000` is a `numeric` and then convert it to `varchar` , I need to convert varchar  to numeric

Comment: @Rocketq isn't the format trick in the answer that I also mentioned of actually a solution to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASTs to VARCHAR are based on the FORMAT (which is COBOL-like) of a column:

```
select cast('0.0000' as numeric(26,4));

'--(22).9(4)'
```

-> A floating minus sign before the first actually needed digit (up to optional 22 digits) and 4 fractional digits, but you need at least one digit plus 4 fractional.

Either change that on a column level or for this specific query:

```
select cast(cast('0.0000' as numeric(26,4) FORMAT '-(22)9.9(4)') as  varchar (32));

0.0000
```

`9` means a digit, e.g. `9(10)` would be 10 digits with leading zeroes.

See [Datatypes and Formats](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1143_109A/ch09.12.01.html) in the Teradata Manuals.

Btw, if you know Oracle syntax and you're running TD14+ you can also use TO_CHAR including most of Oracle's format options.

Comment: Wow, fantastic)) But what does nines here`-(22)9.9(4)`  mean?